# Simple Parameter Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, dom, parameters

I haven't played with Javascript for awhile and I'm scratching my head here...

I have an object I've defined:

```
var attrs = {
    "charStats": {
        "hp": 500000,
        "speed": 1,
        "juice": 0,
        "nova": 0,
        "special": 1,
        "experience": 0,
        "level": 1
        }
    };
```

And the HTML to back it up and display the data:

```
<div class="block">
    <h2>Character Statistics</h2>
    <ul class="statistics">
        <li>HP: <span class="hp"></span></li>
        <li>Speed: <span class="speed"></span></li>
        <li>Juice: <span class="juice"></span></li>
        <li>Special: <span class="special"></span></li>
        <li>Nova: <span class="nova"></span></li>
        <li>Experience: <span class="experience"></span></li>
        <li>Level: <span class="level"></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="block">
    <button class="addExp">Add Experience</button>
</div>

<button class="updateStats">Update</button>
```

So the issue I'm experiencing is one of my functions works, like so:

```
function addToStats(amount){
    attrs.charStats.experience += amount;
}
$('.addExp').on('click', function(){
    addToStats(15);
});
```

But for some reason trying to make it more expandable, setting 2 parameters doesn't seem to work at all...

```
function addToStats(stat, amount){
    stat += amount;
}
$('.addExp').on('click', function(){
    addToStats(attrs.charStats.experience, 15);
});
```

**What exactly am I missing here?**

Working:
http://jsfiddle.net/wu61owt6/

Not Working:
http://jsfiddle.net/wu61owt6/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`attrs.charStats.experience` is just a number, so when you do this:

```
addToStats(attrs.charStats.experience, 15);
```

it is like you are just doing this:

```
addToStats(0, 15);
```

Primitive values in javascript like numbers are passed by value.  They don't pass a pointer or reference to the field in the object, they just pass the value so there is no way to change the original property when just the number was passed.

---

You can pass an object reference to a parent object.  So, you could do this:

```
function addToStats(obj, field, val) {
    obj[field] += val;
}

addToStats(attrs.charStats, "experience", 15);
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is your miss understanding of Pass by reference VS pass by value.

You are not passing a reference in the call, you are passing the value.

So in reality you are doing

```
20 += 1;
```

If you change the code to be like this it will work.

```
function addToStats(stats, prop, amount){
    stats[prop] += amount;
}
$('.addExp').on('click', function(){
    addToStats(attrs.charStats,"experience", 15);
});
```

Comment: Your answer works as well as the other one, but I feel he explained it better. Tyvm.